# Visual Studio 2012 Unable to read project file

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8

I am trying to create a Visual C++ Windows Phone Runtime Project in Visual Studio 2012. When I do, I get this error:

"Unable to read the project file "RT1.vcxproj(150,3): The imported project C:\Program Files(x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft\WindowsPhone\v7.0\Microsoft.Cpp.Windows Phone.7.0.targets" was not found. Confirm that the path in the  declaration is correct, and that the file exists on disk.

First a little clarification - does it create the project, then look in that path for the proper tool to read and open it? If not why is it trying to import anything?

The path it is complaining about doesn't exist, but replace the 7's with 8's and everything is there. Is there a way to change this import declaration to reflect the correct path? Is it trying to create a windows phone runtime component for Windows phone 7 and I just need to specify somewhere it should be creating it for windows phone 8?

EDIT: To add, any visual c++ windows phone project I try to create comes back with basically the same error message.

Comment: If this project is part of a solution, try removing the project from the solution and try re-adding it, this will link up to the "new" path

Comment: When I open visual studio, I pick new project -> templates -> visual c++ -> Windows Runtime Component, as soon as I hit ok I get the error, but it does create the project file, but nothing is in the solution explorer within VS. I go over to the project I intend adding this project to and select add project in the solution, when I select the project file I get the same error as when I tried creating it.